# Log don't display all the data

Tags: java, spring-boot

I se spring boot 2.

I have a method who use a scheduler.
I try to log some info

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 52 8 * * *")
private void sendEmailOrders() throws MessagingException {
    List<FactoryEmailNCDto> factoryEmails = prepareDataNoncompliantSampling();

    log.info("start sendEmailOrders: " + factoryEmails != null ? String.valueOf(factoryEmails.size()) : "0");

    for (FactoryEmailNCDto factoryEmail : factoryEmails) {

        String message = mailContentBuilder.build(factoryEmail);
        if (factoryEmail.getEmails() != null && !factoryEmail.getEmails().isEmpty()) {
            log.info("prepare to sent email to : " + factoryEmail.getFactoryName());
            mailService.sendHtmlMail(factoryEmail.getEmails(), "Order", message);
        }
    }

    log.info("end sendEmailOrders");
}
```

I get

> 2019-03-19 08:52:00.379  INFO 17831 --- [   scheduling-1]
>   com.mermacon.facade.OrdersFacade  : 2 2019-03-19 08:52:00.760  INFO
>   17831 --- [   scheduling-1] com.mermacon.facade.OrdersFacade  :
>   prepare to sent email to : NY 2019-03-19 08:52:03.898 ERROR 17831 ---
>   [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    :
>   Unexpected e

Why I don't get this string: start sendEmailOrders in the log?

Comment: Because I think you getting error inside the log.info(). Try with pure string and find error part.

Comment: strangely if i display only string in the first log.info and create another one to display number... that work... after there is an error when email is sent... so the last log.info is not displayed.